# How do I mock a Kotlin function type returning a value class with Mockk?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I have a test subject that takes a function type in its constructor:

```
class PricedStockListLoader(
    val stock: Stock,
    val pricing: (Item) -> Price?
)
```

In my test I can mock both dependencies:

```
val stock: Stock = mockk()
val pricing: (Item) -> Price? = mockk()
val loader = PricedStockListLoader(stock, pricing)
```

and specify expectations on the `stock`

```
every { stock.stockList(sameDayAsLastModified) } returns Success(stockList)
```

but if I try to specify an expectation on `pricing`

```
every { pricing.invoke(anItem) } returns Price(666)
```

that line (the one specifying the expectation) never returns, stuck on an Object.wait somewhere inside JUnit.

Can I mock function types returning value classes?

Comment: Why mock it though if you can just instantiate it? `val pricing = { item: Item -> if (item == anItem) Price(666) }`.

Comment: If somebody interested, I put together example from the video to play with https://github.com/IRus/gilded-rose-tdd/tree/reproduce-mockk-issue

Comment: Changing `Price` from inline class, to regular solves the issue

Comment: That's awesome @Ruslan - good to see someone who's following my videos!

Comment: Now I've just got to work out what to do with this question. I think I may edit it to be answerable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue related to mocking inline classes.

Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
@JvmInline
value class Foo(val bar: String)

val f: () -> Foo = mockk()

@Test
fun `test value`() {
    every { f.invoke() } returns Foo("test")
    f.invoke()
}
```

Comment: Only appears to be an issue with functions -     interface IBar {
        fun bar() : Foo
    }
    val bar = mockk<(IBar)>()

    @Test fun test() {
        every { bar.bar() } returns Foo("test")
    } is fine

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/977